# Custom error code class and numbers for Postgres stored functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, error-handling

I'm writing a collection of stored functions in Postgres 11.5, and want to `RAISE EXCEPTION` when various pre-conditions are not met. For example, a `null` or empty string with a string is required, or an integer parameter that is out of range, etc.

I can `RAISE EXCEPTION` and provide details, hints, and a message...but what range should I use for the error code? I've checked the docs, but didn't find any guidance here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/errcodes-appendix.html

I searched on StackOverflow, found a similar question from years ago...but not a clear answer.

Is there some block or prefix that's safe or conventional to use for custom error codes coming back from stored functions/procedures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL standard gives you a guideline:

> The character string value returned in an `SQLSTATE` parameter comprises a 2-character class value followed
> by a 3-character subclass value, each with an implementation-defined character set that has a one-octet character
> encoding form and is restricted to <digit>s and <simple Latin upper case letter>s. Table 33, “`SQLSTATE` class
> and subclass values”, specifies the class value for each condition and the subclass value or values for each class
> value.
>
> Class values that begin with one of the <digit>s '0', '1', '2', '3', or '4' or one of the <simple Latin upper case letter>s
> 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', or 'H' are returned only for conditions defined in ISO/IEC 9075 or in any other
> International Standard. The range of such class values is called *standard-defined classes*. Some such class codes
> are reserved for use by specific International Standards, as specified elsewhere in this Clause. Subclass values
> associated with such classes that also begin with one of those 13 characters are returned only for conditions
> defined in ISO/IEC 9075 or some other International Standard. The range of such subclass values is called
> *standard-defined subclasses*. Subclass values associated with such classes that begin with one of the <digit>s
> '5', '6', '7', '8', or '9' or one of the <simple Latin upper case letter>s 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
> 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', or 'Z' are reserved for implementation-defined conditions and are called *implementation-defined subclasses*.
>
> Class values that begin with one of the <digit>s '5', '6', '7', '8', or '9' or one of the <simple Latin upper case letter>s
> 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', or 'Z' are reserved for implementation-defined
> exception conditions and are called *implementation-defined classes*. All subclass values except '000', which
> means *no subclass*, associated with such classes are reserved for implementation-defined conditions and are
> called *implementation-defined subclasses*. An implementation-defined completion condition shall be indicated
> by returning an implementation-defined subclass in conjunction with one of the classes *successful completion*, *warning*, or *no data*.

If your exception matches one of the SQLSTATEs in Appendix A of the PostgreSQL documentation, simply use that SQLSTATE.

If you need to use your own SQLSTATE, let it begin with any of `5` to `9` or `I` to `Z` (but avoid the SQLSTATEs used by PostgreSQL).

If you need to define a custom warning, use an SQLSTATE that starts with `01` and whose third character is any of `5` to `9` or `I` to `Z`.

Comment: "*let it begin with any of 5 to 9 or I to Z.*" - notice that Postgres itself does use `P0` and `XX` already